# Insert to multiple foreign key tables in MVC with super-type/sub-type database-first model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two sub-types of a super-type "Entity", namely "Household" and "Involved Body".

I've modeled them as shown below in my database and they were auto-generated to the EF Model (again shown below).

**database**
[image]

**edmx model**
[image]

Using the default scaffolding for MVC I am able to add a new Household without any problems. However, when I try to add a new Involved Body I hit an error when it tries to add the Entity Type.

There only relevant (as far as I can tell) difference between the two sub-types is that the EntityType for a Household is hard-coded as "Household" whereas the EntityType for an Involved Body can be any EntityType except "Household" - this is selected from a list by the user.

The Create Action on the HTTP POST for the Involved Body throws an error relating to the foreign key between tEntity and tEntityType with the tEntityType being null. Code as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "entityID")]tEntity tentity            
                                                        , tInvolvedBody tinvolvedbody
                                                        , tAddress taddress
                                                        , tAddressEntity taddressentity
                                                        //, tEntityType tentitytype
                                                        , int entityTypeID
                                                        )
{

    #region entity type
    //find entity type from id
    var tentitytype = db.tEntityTypes.Find(entityTypeID);                     

    #endregion

    #region address
    //assume start date of involved body not needed for reporting
    taddressentity.startDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

    #endregion


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.tEntities.Add(tentity);
        db.tInvolvedBodies.Add(tinvolvedbody);
        db.tAddresses.Add(taddress);
        db.tAddressEntities.Add(taddressentity);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //recreate viewbag for entityType dropdown
    var q = (
            from e in db.tEntityTypes
            where e.entityType != "Household"
            select e
        );

    ViewBag.entityTypeID = new SelectList(q, "entityTypeID", "entityType");
    return View(tinvolvedbody);
}
```

I've tried adding the tEntityType to the parameters list for the create but this results in the ModelState.IsValid returning false due to the entityType being null on all the objects.

I've also tried actively linking the entity type to each of the other objects using:

```
tentity.tEntityType = tentitytype;
tinvolvedbody.tEntity.tEntityType = tentitytype;
taddressentity.tEntity.tEntityType = tentitytype;
```

The above ends up working but it creates a new Entity for each of the other objects i.e. I get three new rows in my tEntity table, one is the Entity, one links to tInvolvedBody and one links to tAddressEntities. This makes no sense...

How can I insert a new InvolvedBody that creates an Entity, picks up the Entity Type and then links to the AddressEntity junction table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked through this. Not sure if the answer is 'perfect' from a developer perspective but it works.

After intense debugging I realised that the navigation properties for the involved body and address entity were both looking for an entitytypeID which I had assumed would be provided by the entity object.

If I passed these in directly with the code shown:

```
tinvolvedbody.tEntity.tEntityType = tentitytype;
taddressentity.tEntity.tEntityType = tentitytype;
```

...I ended up with three new entitites and no relational data existing between all of {entity, involved body, address}

The code that works removes the explicit addition of a new entity and relies on EF to create an entity from the Involved Body. I then used the newly created entityID to map the address via addressentity as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="entityID")]tEntity tentity
                                                    ,tInvolvedBody tinvolvedbody
                                                    ,tAddress taddress
                                                    ,tAddressEntity taddressentity
                                                    ,int entityTypeID
                                                    )
{

    #region entity type
    var t =
            (
                from e in db.tEntityTypes
                where (e.entityTypeID == entityTypeID)
                select e
            );

    tinvolvedbody.tEntity.tEntityType = t.First();
    #endregion

    #region address
    //assume start date of involved body not needed for reporting
    taddressentity.startDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

    #endregion

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.tInvolvedBodies.Add(tinvolvedbody);                
        db.tAddresses.Add(taddress);

        taddressentity.tEntity = db.tEntities.Find(tinvolvedbody.bodyID);

        db.tAddressEntities.Add(taddressentity);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the typeID specifically?  Also, from what I gathered from your model, the taddress is a child of taddressentity?  As such, should it not be inserted first in order for the foreign key?

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        tentity.entityTypeID = entityTypeID;
        db.tEntities.Add(tentity);

        tinvolvebody.bodyID= tentity.entityID
        db.tInvolvedBodies.Add(tinvolvedbody);

        taddressentity.entityID = tentity.entityID;
        db.tAddressEntities.Add(taddressentity);

        taddress.UPRN = taddressentity.UPRN;
        db.tAddresses.Add(taddress);



        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: This throws an error I was getting earlier referring to the Foreign Key constraint between tEntity and tEntityType. If I look at the ModelState in the debugger it shows the tEntityType of each object as being NULL.

Comment: @melkisadek Have you verified through debug that the EntityTypeID being sent to the controller actually matches to a EntityTypeID?

Comment: @TNCM - Yes, the debugger shows a correct value for the EntityTypeID. What it won't do is navigate the EF Model without me specifically adding the Entity Type as shown in the original post. If I add (uncomment) tEntityType to the Create parameter list then I get an invalid model for the key "entityType". If I uncomment the code linking the entityTypes to each object then I still get additional rows.

Comment: @melkisadek I will keep this running in the back of my mind, and let you know if I think of anything.  But, for now, I am pretty much out of ideas.  I really hope you get it worked out.

Comment: @TNCM - thanks for the help - I've figured out a solution although I'm still not sure why the two sub-types work differently. I've added the finished code to a separate answer.